# How to convert alt code to special character

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

Suppose I have an integer value of 26, how would I go about turning it into the <kbd>Alt+26</kbd> `→` character and add it to an `FString` in Unreal Engine?

Comment: Although you have already tagged your question with `#unreal-engine5`, you may want to clarify that you are referring to an [Unreal Engine FString](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/ProgrammingWithCPP/UnrealArchitecture/StringHandling/FString/). Otherwise, people who are unfamiliar with Unreal Engine might think that "FString" is a typo and that you meant to write "String", so that they might erroneously assume that you are asking a general question about strings.

Comment: You build a table (map) that maps alt codes to characters. You should be aware that arrows may or may not be available as `char` values depending on your code page. You probably should be using `wchar_t` (or, if working in UTF-8, a string type) instead.

Answer (score 2):

n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. Gave me the answer:

Create a map of int to FString (char and wchar_t didn't work probably because of the code page).

```
std::map<int, FString> specChars{
{26, FString(TEXT("→"))}
};
```

Find the key, add its value to your output string:

```
auto search = specChars.find(26);
if (search != specChars.end()) {
    MyFString += search->second;
}
```